# How come we are looking at negative z by default in openGL?

Tags: opengl

I have this code

```
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);// red quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1, 0, -0.1); 
glVertex3f(1, 0, -0.1);
glVertex3f(1, 1, -0.1);
glVertex3f(-1, 1, -0.1);
glEnd();

glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //green quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1, 0, -0.2);
glVertex3f(1, 0, -0.2);
glVertex3f(1, 1, -0.2);
glVertex3f(-1, 1, -0.2);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Using default projection matrix, the one that appears is my green quad. 
If we're looking to negative z (from 1 to -1), shouldn't the green quad behind the red quad?

Comment: Have you enabled depth testing?

Comment: Define "default projection matrix".

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm only saying that I didn't change the projection matrix. I've read that the default is the same as glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1), according to https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/145698-what-is-the-default-projection-matrix

Answer (score 1):

All matrices in compatibility mode OpenGL start off as identity matrices; they don't apply any transformations.

In Normalized Device Coordinates, +Z is into the window; you're looking at +Z. Matrices and shaders can, of course, change this.

Also make sure that depth testing is enabled and you create your window with a depth buffer.

Comment: Hi, I had depth testing enabled, depth is working okay, thanks. any way I can confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

If red quad is outside frustum's near and far plane then your red quad will not be visible because it gets clipped out. [More information](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)

Comment: How do you setup your model-view matrix?

Comment: everything is default, so I guess they must be identity matrix.. :)